# Download FTP data using SSH

Tags: ssh, debian, putty

I need to transfer files from one server to the other. Normally I just download the files and then upload em to the new server using FTP.

Now I am facing a gazillion files with over 15GB data. Is it possible to download em directly from the new server, thereby skipping a step? I have full control over the second server, but just FTP rights on the old server.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `wget` on the new server to download the data from the old server. Something like

```
$ wget -r -N -l inf 'ftp://old.example.com/'
```

should do it. Consult the man page if you need anything more specific; wget is quite powerful.

Alternatively, FTP can be directly used to transfer from server to server. Since FTP uses separate control and data connections, the data connection can be established to a different host than that from which the control connection originates. This is done by switching one of the servers into passive mode. I think that [SecureFX](https://www.vandyke.com/products/securefx/index.html) supports that mode of operation by opening connections to both servers and dragging-and-dropping files between them. However, I don't know if there is any free software that can do that.

Answer (score 3):

If you have commandline access via SSH to your new server, just open a session on the new server and within that session do an FTP "mget" from the old server.

There is a summary of commandline FTP here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-ftp-commands/